# given url is not allowed by the application configuration.facebook login error

Tags: facebook, xamarin, facebook-login

I am developing an andriod app using xamarin studio and this is my first mobile app. I am trying to integrate with Facebook login. As per the pre-requistes i have created an app in developers page in facebook and have included the app_id in my code. But when i try to connect to the facebook login i get this error . I have installed the facebook sdk as well in my emulator.

**given url is not allowed by the application configuration.: one or more of the given urls is not allowed by the app's settings. it must match the website url or canvas url, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the app's domains.**

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Let me know if the sample project worked for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Auth Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435598/xamarin-auth-facebook)

Comment: Alex, sorry was working on another important stuff. will update you once i check it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [Facebook Android SDK](http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid) component if you have not already.
Then execute the `Facebook Android Sample` project? You can use the sample code as a reference for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Good luck.

Comment: Alex,but the sample projects are in java right. Do you have links to c# sample

Comment: @vivinmathew They are in C# so check them out

Answer (score 0):

App Domain: localhost

Web Site Url: http(s)://localhost:port

Oauth Redir URL: https://.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler